# Different icon to items in expandiblelistview

Tags: android, icons

Is it possible to assign different icon to each item in a group? Can anyone show me an example? I would like a result like this:

[image: example]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) of `ExpandableListAdapter`:

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent):

Gets a View that displays the data for the given child within the given group.
```

This is the method that returns the `View` of the child, which means you could write something like this in your `ExpandableListAdapter`:

```
@Override 
public View getChildView(int gPos, int cPos, bool isLast, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever, null);
    }
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    // This next part depends on how you store the images. 
    // You could store the imageID in an int[][]:
    int imageID = carImages[gPos][cPos];
    image.setImageResource(imageID);

    // or you could store the drawable in a List<List<Drawable>>
    Drawable d = carimages.get(gPos).get(cPos);
    iamge.setImageDrawable(d);

    // etc.

    return view;
}
```

The point is that you have to store the images in a way that you can retreive the right image by providing which index the view has, and in which group it is in. 
You could also store the image in a `CarObject`, and have a `List<CarObject>` in your adapter. But you would have to find a way to distinguish between the different brands.

Comment: Right. It could be possible giving the right position of the element?

Comment: The real challenge is to have your data (text, image, etc.) in a way that makes it easy to get the correct data, by only providing two indices. My best guess would be a List<List<CarObject>> type of approach, so the top list is a list of lists, where each list represents a car branding (say, BMW, or Porche). The inner list (for each branding), would then contain the cars. In you image, the BMW M6 would have indices (1,0) (BMW is the second branding, index 1, and M6 is the first car, index 0).